Issues when appending new element
I have an issue with this error code "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'append')"
In this case, the container I want to append the new P to, is undefined. Which doesnt make sense to me since the container is retrieved through getElementById of an ID in the markup.
Here is my code:
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Annoying Diary</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container text-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col heading-container">
          <h1 class="heading">Diary</h1>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col heading-container">
          **<div id="newPShow">KEY DOWN HERE</div>**
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <textarea name="" id="textArea" rows="20"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row row-padding">
        <div class="col">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-dark btn-width" type="button">
            Button
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

const textInput = document.querySelector("#textArea");
let newP = document.createElement("p");
**let container = document.getElementById(newPShow);**

textInput.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
  console.log(e.code);
  newP.innerText = e.code;
  document.container.append(newP);
});


I have tried creating a new container and append to body. Problem is that the keydown events are then shown on the bottom of the page. I want it to be shown in a specififc DIV, and as you can see, there are a few divs in this markup.
